# What is the best way to check for XHR2 file upload support?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, browser-support

If XHR2 is supported with file-upload capabilites, my application needs to do different preparation.  What is a safe way to check if these capabilities are supported.  Is it sufficient, for example, to just check an `XMLHttpRequest` (or MS equivalents) for the `upload` property?  like...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (typeof xhr.upload !== "undefined") {
  do nice stuff
}
else {
  do oldschool stuff
}
```

Or is this not safe?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
if (new XMLHttpRequest().upload) {
  // welcome home!
} else {
  // not supported
}
```